# Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance) does not add extra encoding providers

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-core, nuget-package, codepages

I am developing a `netcoreapp2.0` console application and I need access to the whole encoding package from .NET.

I have already added the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages Version=4.4.0` Nuget package from [this page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) to my project and cleaned/restored the project several time.

However I can't get the extra encoding I need.

The following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncodings().Length);
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncodings().Length);
```

returns:

```
8
8
```

and no extra encoding is added to `Encoding` class.

These are all the references I have in my project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.HashFunction.xxHash" Version="2.0.0-ci-00012" />
<PackageReference Include="Nager.PublicSuffix" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />

<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Update**

After reinstalling the .NET Core SDK 2.0.2 again, things started to work fine and I can use the extended Encoding code pages using `Encoding.GetEncoding()` method, however the `Encoding.GetEncodings()` still returns the initial 8 Encoding code pages.

Comment: Isn't your packages.config missing a reference to Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 2.0? It is a dependency for that lib.

Comment: Well as far as I can see in Visual Studio, it has been already loaded as part of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` SDK set by`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` in my project @GabrielRainha however I tried adding `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="2.0.0" />` and unfortunatly it didn't help.

Comment: Add your update as the answer. It might help people from the future.

Comment: @RojanGh. did you get around this issue?

Comment: @JoeB it seems like, all the extra encodings are actually added and being used by Encoding class, however they are not being added to the list of Encodings when you call Encoding.GetEncoding() and because I didn't really need the list and I just wanted it to work, I didn't get much further with the investigation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update August 2022:**

Thanks to a comment from [zapoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411936/zapoo), we know that while the solution is not required in .net framework 4.8, it is needed for .net 6.0

---

I am adding this as the answer regarding [Gabriel Rainha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4905310/gabriel-rainha)'s suggestion that it might help other people in the future too.

I cleaned the Nuget cache, repaired my ".NET Core SDK 2.0.2" installation, did a "Solution and Project Cleanup" and rebuilt my project, and the `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)` code started to work fine.

Now I can access the extra code pages using the `Encoding.GetEncoding()` method, however I still get the same list of encodings from `Encoding.GetEncodings()` method after adding the extra encodings.

From my perspective the `Encoding.GetEncodings()` method should return all the encodings available after more of them have been added.

Comment: Why is this line of code necessary to the program:
`Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)`. 
I use this line in my code as well, but dont know why it's necessary

Comment: I haven't dug into the code @BijanNegari and I might be wrong but from the look of it, I can say that the providers that are missing will be added to the ones already available by the framework.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but wasn't sure. Thanks

Comment: Adding 
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance) helped me on Azure Functions.

Comment: @zapoo I’m happy this still helping after so many years. :)

Comment: @RojanGh. Thanks for the solution, also I want to mention that the code I have was working fine in the .net framework 4.8 but not in .Net 6., so I did the searching and found your answer.

Comment: @zapoo thanks for letting me know! I will add that to the answer too. :)

Answer (score -2):

install nuget packages:
System.Text.Encoding & System.Text.Encoding.CodePages

Comment: The question clearly mentions that the Nuget packages are installed.

Comment: after i installed, it worked for me perfectly.

just try unloading project , closing & reopen visual studio also

might workout i think so